# why multi-line command will make smaller size than single-line when i use yum install in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos, yum, docker-image

I have 2 Dockerfile.

First is

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y kde-l10n-Chinese && \
    yum install -y glibc-common
```

and other is

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y 
RUN yum install -y kde-l10n-Chinese 
RUN yum install -y glibc-common
```

the docker image i get is like:

[image]

It bothers me, the official documentation says because of the number of layers, but I understand that each layer reuses the previous one, so there's no reason they should be 300mb different。

I would appreciate it if anyone could look into this problem for me. thank you.

when i use `dive level:multi`, it show me like:

[image]

---

[image]

---

the module i use is like: (excluded unmodified file)

[image]

Comment: can you post the output of `docker manifest inspect level:one` and `docker manifest inspect level:multi`?

Comment: Because the dockerfile is write by my self and build on my local machine, so the output is: "no such manifest: docker.io/cloudstyle/level:multi".